# How to test redirection through navigation items in Nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch

without further do, I will cut to the chase:

I have some anchor tags with `iterated-item` as a css class. All I want is to iterate through them, click them and test the redirected url of the browser.

I have tried using `elements` but I get the stale error:

`Error while running .clickElement() protocol action: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

which kinda makes sense actually. However, I cannot find any way to dynamically get the looped items, iterate through them, click the first, check the url, go back, click the second, check the url, go back and so on.

Here is my little piece of nightwatch code:

```
 browser.url(browser.launchUrl)
 browser.waitForElementVisible('#my-whatever-container')
 browser
   .elements('css selector', '.iterated-item', function (links) {
     links.value.forEach((link) => {
       browser.pause(1000)
       browser.elementIdClick(link.ELEMENT)
       browser.waitForElementVisible('#my-whatever-element')
       browser
         .expect.url().to.contain('something-in-the-url')
       browser
         .back()
     })
   })
 browser.end()
```

This works for the first iteration but when it goes back, I get the `stale` error and everything goes bananas.

Answer (score 0):

After giving it one last shot, I managed to do it with a hacky solution, but hey, it worked!

```
browser.url(browser.launchUrl)
    browser.waitForElementVisible('#my-whatever-container')

    browser.elements('css selector', '.iterated-item', function (links) {
      // get dynamically the length of the iterated items
      // and just use the index for the rest of the code
      const linksLength = links.value.length
      for (let i = 0; i < linksLength; i++) {
        browser.waitForElementVisible('#my-whatever-container')
        // with every iteration, refresh the iterated items
        // which are bound to the current page view
        browser.elements('css selector', '.iterated-item', function (linksRenewed) {
          browser.elementIdClick(linksRenewed.value[i].ELEMENT)
          browser.waitForElementVisible('#my-whatever-element')
          browser.expect.url().to.contain('something-in-the-url')
          browser.back()
        })
      }
    })
    browser.end()
```